# Perl equivalent of PHP_AUTH_PW

Tags: php, perl, jquery, cgi

I am working with cross-domain AJAX in jquery, using a local forwarding script in the middle, and I need to pass Basic Authentication information through to the second domain.
In PHP, I know I have access to `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` variables which are simple plaintext, so my forwarding script can use this information with no difficulty.

For reasons beyond my control, though, I have to perform this task with Perl CGI.  I know there is `$ENV{REMOTE_USER}`, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to find the password.  I've tried `$ENV{HTTP_AUTHORIZATION}` but that always comes out blank.

How, in Perl, can I read the Basic Authentication password?  Or, at least, is there a way for my CGI to directly read the Authorization header so I can base64-decode and split the string myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Before you suggest it, mod_perl is also not an option.

Comment: You know that you have to send a 401 response back before the client will send an Authorization header?

Comment: The actual authentication is already being handled fine by apache. If I go to my test webpage in a browser, I get the username/password popup and my script can successfully display REMOTE_USER. It's just the password I'm not sure how to get at, which I fear might already be inaccessible by the CGI layer.

Comment: additional angle to the question: Is there anything I could add to a .htaccess file, or something like that, to store the info in an environment variable?

Comment: if apache is already handling the auth through `mod_auth_whatever`, then `REMOTE_USER` is all you get. It strips out  everything else.

Comment: I recall writing a custom Apache module to put the password into an environment variable. The existing authentication module doesn't add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article: http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html .

It uses ModReWrite to write the Http Authorization header to an environment variable. You can then access and decode this in your CGI script.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```